# Split string between character +

Tags: r

I want to get all the words in a string that are between `+`. This seems really obvious, but it's not working.

Why does this not work?

```
text <- "x+y+z"

strsplit(text, "+")

[[1]]
[1] "x" "+" "y" "+" "z"
```

I want `x`, `y`, and `z` as separate elements in a vector, such as

```
newtext <- c("x", "y", "z")
```

Comment: You need to escape the `+`: `strsplit(text, "\\+")`

Comment: @d.b Thanks. I knew it was something simple I was missing

Comment: Or add `fixed = TRUE`